# Nginx location and rewrite

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I'm dealing with the following issue and I can't figure out to resolve it.
I have HAproxy in front of app server farm which are running nginx.
HAproxy has some httpchecks enabled for backend services - the checks are hitting /health_check URI:

```
option httpchk HEAD /health_check HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ staging.example.com
```

What I can't figure out is how to avoid logging for Virtualhosts which have permanent rewrites enabled for all URIs.
Here's the example

```
server {
  listen      8000;
  server_name "";

  location = /health_check {
    access_log off;
    return 200;
  }

  rewrite     ^(.*)   https://staging.example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

I thought the above location directive would disable the logs for given URI but I was wrong - it's being completely ignored.

is there any way how to acomplish something like this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `rewrite` in a `location /` block.

```
location / {
    rewrite     ^(.*)   https://staging.example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

This way, it will match all URLs except for `/health_check` which has a more specific `location`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also return rather than rewrite using a `location /` block if you don't need the regex.

```
location / {
    return   301   $scheme://staging.example.com$request_uri;
}
```